# Specifying classpath in TomEE 1.7/Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, classpath, openejb, apache-tomee

We have a large web application deployed in an EAR within TomEE 1.7 (based on Tomcat 7).  The basic structure of the app is:

- app

  - webapp1
  - webapp2
- lib

  - jar1
  - jar2
  - jar3
  - patch.jar

Where the applications share common jars is in the lib folder.  Pretty standard EAR configuration.  In order to make delivering fixes easier, we added a jar called "patch.jar" to the lib folder.  We would then modify the MANIFEST.MF in the META-INF folder to have an explicit class-path configured and have path.jar at the front.  In that way, if we added a class, the application would find it.  And if we fixed a class we would put a copy of that updated class in patch.jar, then because of the class-path designation, the app would find the updated class first and use it.

That allows us to, when we are delivering a patch, so just deliver a single JAR.  Much smaller, quicker, and safer (since we are only delivering a small number of updated classes and not the entire application).

This worked fine when we deployed in JBoss, but now that we've moved to TomEE, we cannot get it to work.  It seems to always ignore any class-path designation.  Is there any way to do this -- to specify an explicit class-path for TomEE EAR applications so that the app will search through a list of jars in sequence?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add in conf/system.properties:

```
xbean.finder.use.get-resources=true
```